Is it possible to store a manual copy of iPhone Backup locally?
I am going to sell my iPhone 12 and get iPhone 15 in a couple months. I was wondering, if I can take a backup of iPhone using iTunes (on Windows) and keep a copy ? Like, in case I decide to format my PC in between, nothing should happen to the backup.
I know I can use iCloud, but I dont want to use that service for apps and stuff. It will increase my expenses. But, if manual backup copy is not permitted, I may not have a choice.

Yes. In the MobileSync\Backup folder, each individual folder is an iPhone backup, and the folder is named by the iPhone's UDID (or starting with the UDID and a date/time after that). You'll want to treat that folder as one atomic unit, you don't want just part of the folder or to move anything around inside the folder.
You can copy the folder, or zip it up and copy it, anywhere you like, such as to an external drive. I have several external drives with over a decade of backups on them, since working with iPhone backups is part of my job :)
I see the link to the Apple Support page about how to find the backups. In addition here's a blog post I wrote about where to find the iPhone backups as well.

You can backup your iPhone to a Windows computer using iTunes for Windows. Below are the steps according to the iPhone User Guide from Apple:

Connect iPhone and your computer with a cable.
In the iTunes app on your PC, click the iPhone button near the top left of the iTunes window.
Click Summary.
Click Back Up Now (below Backups).
To encrypt your backups, select “Encrypt local backup,” type a password, then click Set Password.


I know that. But, what if I format my PC, by the time, I get a new iPhone ? I am going out for a couple weeks, and I am ordering my iPhone after that

In case you decide to format your PC after taking a back up of your iPhone, you should take a backup of your PC first. Then, you can use that backup to restore the iTunes files if and when necessary.

On another note, you can locate the iPhone backup file on your PC once you use iTunes as described in my answer. To do that, take a look at this Apple support page. I assume you can then copy that file to a USB memory stick, but I am not 100% sure if you can simply put it back later on after deleting the original backup file.
